# How to generate low-memory and high disk IO for testing?

Tags: testing, memory, load, disk

I'm developing a windows application. Currently it's a .NET application on Windows 7 PCs.

I would like to test the performance of my app under conditions where the user may have other memory-intensive applications open as well as cases where there are other heavy hard disk accessing applications in use.

Are there accepted ways to test this?

For the memory test I can write a separate application to allocate memory in various configurations (one big array, linked list of many smaller (or larger) nodes) etc...

The disk access is trickier to me because I'm not even sure how to correctly measure how much load a separate load-generation app would be imparting, other than running various scenarios: creating a large file, deleting or copying, creating many small files etc...

I feel like these problems maybe already solved by some software I just haven't found yet. Or maybe everyone writes their own for their specific needs?